# JavaScript Regex replacing multiple patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to modify the regex, which does the following for me.

Changes the IP list, the list can be longer or shorter.

```
1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2
```

to a string such as:

```
[{"{#ADDR}":"1.1.1.1"},{"{#ADDR}":" 2.2.2.2"}]
```

in the following line:

```
return '{$PING_LIST}'.replace(/([^,]+)/g,'{"{#ADDR}":"$1"}').replace(/(.*)/,'[$1]')
```

But I need to add the hostname to the list as well.

```
1.1.1.1-NODE1,2.2.2.2-NODE2
```

and get something like this

```
[{"{#ADDR}":"1.1.1.1","{#NODE}":"NODE1"},{"{#ADDR}":"2.2.2.2","{#NODE}":"NODE2"}]
```

I tried to get the hostname, this way:

```
(?<=-)(\w+)(?=,)
```

but I can't figure out the correct syntax and combine it with the previous expression.

Very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)` to match the IP.

```js
let pinglist = '1.1.1.1-NODE1,2.2.2.2-NODE2';
let result = pinglist.replace(/((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)-([^,]+)/g, '{"{#ADDR}":"$1","{#NODE}":"$2"}')
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your desired result string looks like a Javascript array with objects. If that is the case, you can use 2 capture groups:

```
\b((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})-(\w+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/94CdAL/1) for the capture group values.

```js
const s = "1.1.1.1-NODE1,2.2.2.2-NODE2";
const regex = /\b((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})-(\w+)/g;
const m = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => {
  return {
    "{#ADDR}": m[1],
    "{#NODE}": m[2]
  }
})
console.log(m);
```